# How to find real display density (DPI) from Java code?

Tags: java, macos, retina-display, dpi, hidpi

I'm going to do some low-level rendering stuff, but I need to know real display DPI for making everything of correct size.

I've found one way to do this:
`java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()` — but it returns incorrect result on OS X with "retina" display, it's 1/2 of the real DPI. (In my case it should be 220, but it's 110)

So either some other, more correct API must be available, or alternatively I need to implement a hack just for OS X — somehow find if the current display is "retina". But I couldn't find any way to query for this information too. There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20767802/1418097) but on my machine `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor")` just returns null.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's currently possible to get it from `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment`. Here's commented code example which does work on latest JDK (8u112).

```
// find the display device of interest
final GraphicsDevice defaultScreenDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

// on OS X, it would be CGraphicsDevice
if (defaultScreenDevice instanceof CGraphicsDevice) {
    final CGraphicsDevice device = (CGraphicsDevice) defaultScreenDevice;

    // this is the missing correction factor, it's equal to 2 on HiDPI a.k.a. Retina displays
    final int scaleFactor = device.getScaleFactor();

    // now we can compute the real DPI of the screen
    final double realDPI = scaleFactor * (device.getXResolution() + device.getYResolution()) / 2;
}
```

Comment: This is platform dependent. On Linux it's `X11GraphicsDevice` and even that's a `sun` class that's normally hidden from the user.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example adopted from @sarge-borsch that won't throw compile errors on Windows and Linux.

```
public static int getScaleFactor() {
    try {
        // Use reflection to avoid compile errors on non-macOS environments
        Object screen = Class.forName("sun.awt.CGraphicsDevice").cast(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice());
        Method getScaleFactor = screen.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getScaleFactor");
        Object obj = getScaleFactor.invoke(screen);
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            return ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to determine screen scale factor.  Defaulting to 1.");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I used something similar in the end as well, just forgot to add it to the answer.

Comment: You don’t need the `null`s, and you don’t need the `Class.forClass` expression either: you can invoke the reflection directly on the `getDefaultScreenDevice()` instance. But beware that the *default* screen isn’t the same as the *current* screen: it’s better to get the graphics configuration of the `Component` to be painted on, and go from there. That way, moving a dialog around on multiple screens will correctly update the rendering.

Comment: I noticed the compile warnings after posting this.  Example updated without the `null` parameters.  In regards to the "Default screen", my example is used for the system tray (no parent Component) so I think it to be correct for my (very specific) use-case.  In regards to `Class.forClass`, I'm not sure what you are recommending so it may make sense as a new answer or an improvement to this one.

Comment: @tresf You simply don’t need the cast at all: just use `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()` directly.

Comment: Thanks.  If used on a non-apple device, wouldn't it be more intuitive to the programmer if the exception message fails on Class.forName rather than Method.invoke?