# Taking a screenshot out of java/kotlin app of mac screen (Retina Display)

Tags: java, macos, kotlin, retina-display, awtrobot

My aim is to find a specific picture on the screen by taking a screenshot of the whole screen and find the picture (saved in the resources of the app) by comparing the pixels.

The problem I´m facing at the moment is the part where I take a screenshot of a MacBookPro with Retina display. The resolution is 2880*1800. But with the following code (working fine on windows), I only get a screenshot with 1920*1200.

```
new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())
```

Obviously the screen size is wrong but even when I use 2880*1800 hardcoded, the screenshot only is 1920*1200 with black frame around.

Does somebody know how to take the screenshot with the right resolution?

Comment: Whats the result of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()`?

Comment: Since Java 9, there is [`Robot.createMultiResolutionScreenCapture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html#createMultiResolutionScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) for the purpose of taking screen captures on displays with scaling transforms. Have you tried that one?

Comment: the Toolkit gave 1920*1200

Comment: @Hulk no I will check this. Thx

Comment: @Hulk `Robot.createMultiResolutionScreenCapture` returns 3840*2400
But that is still not the right resolution.

Comment: It should be possible to get the "real" resolution from the `GraphicsDevice` - along the lines of [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399909/2513200)